# Views: sort criteria -> Post date, not start from latest but latest-3

Tags: views

is there a possibility to sort articles by postdate, but exclude the latest 3 and start with number 4 (because the latest 3 are already displayed in another view).

Or even better: is there in general a possibility to exclude articles already displayed on the same page but in another view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the `Use Pager` options, you can specify an offset, which by default is 0, but can be any number, which, amusingly, in the help section offers:

```
The number of items to skip. For example, if this field is 3, the first 3 items will be skipped and not displayed.
```